# Firefox Webconsole Jquery AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery, firefox, firebug

I'm having a weird issue that I hope someone could help me out with. I am troubleshooting a JQuery ajax issue.  Here is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: logging.url + '/register',
  success: function(a) {
  console.log('success:', a, a.client_ip, a["client_ip"]);
}
```

When looking at the ajax response I see something very strange and can't figure it out:

```
success: {
  "session_id": "3423423123",
  "client_ip": "127.0.0.1"
} undefined undefined
```

**I can't figure out why those last 2 are undefined!**

I'm also stuck in the firefox console when I'm used to the chrome console.  I've tried to do things like `window.DATA = a` to look at the object in Firefox console but this doesn't seem to work for some reason.  There is no DATA variable under window when I do this and this is how I usually troubleshoot in chrome.

So the two problems I have are:

1. why can I see the object elements in the console, but can't access them
2. how can I send things to `window` to look at them.

Comment: Not sure about the firefox console, as I use chrome too :) But just to be silly, the ajax response is being returned with json headers set right?

Comment: Ahh, the server side code is right, but you did point me in the right direction!!  I need to set the dataType to 'json' on the ajax call.  This worked fine in chrome for some reason, but firefox needed to be told it was expecting json back, weird! Thanks a lot!